# Invoke Rich Modal Panel Onclick

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using the following code for displaying dynamic image in rich DataTable.
Onclick of the thumbnail I need to display Full Image fetched from different location.

But the second a4j:mediaOutput tag is fetching all the Full images and keeping in memory.
(Ofcourse modalPanel is displayed on click only )

I want the second a4j:mediaOutput tag to call daImageRetrievalBean.retrieveFullImage only after click.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <h:outputLink value="#" id="link">
                            <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" cacheable="false" session="true" style="height:75px; width:75px;"
                                createContent="#{daImageRetrievalBean.retrieveThumbnail}" value="#{digAsset.digitalAssetId}" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
                            <rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="link" operation="show" event="onclick">
                            </rich:componentControl>
                        </h:outputLink>
                        <rich:modalPanel id="panel" resizeable="false" autosized="true" minHeight="650" minWidth="700">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{digAsset.fileName}     Click on the image to hide" />
                            </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="controls">
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" cacheable="false" session="true" id="hidelink" style="height:600px; width:700px;margin-top: 30px"
                                            createContent="#{daImageRetrievalBean.retrieveFullImage}" value="#{digAsset.fileName}" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
                                <rich:componentControl for="panel" attachTo="hidelink" operation="hide" event="onclick"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>                      
                        </rich:modalPanel>
```